# Sphinx doesn't respect :widths: attribute for tables (rtd-theme)

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, read-the-docs

I declare a table for sphinx using this syntax:

```
.. list-table::
   :header-rows: 1
   :widths: 1 1 2

   * - Platzhalter
     - Beispiel
     - Beschreibung
   * - <from_date>
     - <from_date>
     - ...
```

But Sphinx is just ignoring the widths attribute somehow as shown below:

[image: sphinx table cut off]

The table clearly doesn't obey my specifications. How can I fix this?

**Note**: I'm using the read the docs theme and I had to put

```
.wy-table-responsive table td,
.wy-table-responsive table th {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

into my layout.html to make tables respect the div border. Maybe it has something to do with this. If I leave out this option I just get a scrollbar which is also not nice :/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grid table does not word-wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69359978/grid-table-does-not-word-wrap)

Comment: Being discussed here: https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx_rtd_theme/issues/1179