# How can I wrap text inside a cell to get a table from a csv file in the Sphinx documentation created using Restructured text (RST) files?

Tags: html, css, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, read-the-docs

I want to add a table from a csv file in the Sphinx documentation.
In the rst file, I used the csv-table directive as follows:

```
.. csv-table:: xyz
        :header-rows: 1
        :file: path/file.csv
        :widths: 20, 30, 50
```

As a result, I get the required table in the Sphinx documentation as shown below:
[image]

I want to wrap text in the third column "Significance". The format should be wrapped text inside the table as shown below. [Source](https://pypsa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components.html):
[image]

I tried different things such as removing widths or changing its values.

I am relatively new to CSS. I tried various suggestions found in the internet. For example, I tried adding following elements to my css file.

```
@import url('theme.css');

.table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
    word-wrap: break-word !important;
    overflow-wrap: break-word !important;
    word-break: break-all !important;
  }
```

And changing the directive in rst file as follows:

```
.. table:: 
    :class: contentstable
    :widths: 100%
    .. csv-table:: Databases in MESSAGE
        :header-rows: 1
        :file: csv_file/message_databases.csv
        :widths: 20 30 50
```

However, these techniques still don't resolve the issue. I tried searching and trying ways to increase rows and so on. I found that it is possible add a new line in rst using a pipe symbol "|". However, I have several csv files to be added as tables. And I don't want to add pipe symbols in texts in individual cells.

How can I wrap the text- increase the row height and reduce the column width of the table in the Sphinx documentation? Scrolling a bit is fine, but scrolling too long makes you lose the important contents in previous columns.

Comment: For custom CSS in Sphinx, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69373882/2214933

Comment: I have been using custom CSS all along, and I also tried the suggestion in the link you shared. But it didn't work for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `:class: longtable`. This is needed when also generating a PDF of the Sphinx docs, especially when it hits the end of a page.

```
.. csv-table:: xyz
    :header-rows: 1
    :file: path/file.csv
    :widths: 20, 30, 50
    :class: longtable
```

Comment: This did not work.